# Would foot weapons be viable in a street fight?

Tags: technology, cities, combat, martial-arts, stealth

There are several weapons that are used to enhance a person's punches. These include brass knuckles, caestus, boxing tape, etc. These weapons are often used in disorganized conflict like bar brawls and gang fights and robberies and other forms of urban combat. However, there is no weapon I'm aware of that is worn or used to enhance a person's kicking power.

Let's say that two ruffians in modern times in a bad part of town get into a scrape at a bar. One ruffian puts on brass knuckles and gets ready to fight. The other ruffian is wielding either steel-toed/steel-heeled boots or boots with a hidden knife that sharpens kicks. Assuming the two ruffians are of equal size and fighting experience, who do you expect to win this fight?

A person can control their arms easier than they can control their legs which is why inexperienced people prefer punches to kicks. A person also has to use their legs to move which will limit combat options. On the other hand, kicks are more powerful than punches and an enhanced kick to the right place can quickly end a fight.

Comment: This is a) unanswerable in its current state and b) does not seem to be a worldbuilding problem. Re a) first, the ruffians may be of equal size and fighting experience, but we don't know what that fighting experience is or their flexibility - if they have both done savate it may be different to if both have done boxing.  Secondly, we don't know what "win this fight" means - is the objective to get the other guy to back down, or put him in hospital, or put him in the morgue?

Comment: "Would a gorilla or an octopus win in a fight?"

Comment: Or there's [King Shark Vs Gorilla Grod](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cXIo3KjXAc). Seems entirely up to you. Writing issue, not worldbuilding one (or biological one). (By which I mean, do you want the underdog to win, then build-up the prowess of the other guy. Accident and opportunity will help the plot more than any definitive answer we can't give you)

Comment: VTC:Too Story-Based. The winner will be the one you want to win. There are far too many variables to guess who would win. Even saying "all other things being equal," the one thing that isn't equal (and too story-based) is who got in the first solid strike? That person wins. Foot weapons would be a wonderful *rationalization for why you wanted that guy to win* and an interesting blow-by-blow story... but there isn't a worldbuilding question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plenty of Gangs/groups historically have included Steel Toe boots as part of their 'uniform' - leading to their nickname 'ShitKickers'.

As you've alluded to - control is one thing, however - probably the bigger impediment is the ability to equip/unequip a Weapon.

Steel Toe boots can be pretty inconspicuous, but anything else is either really uncomfortable (Shin guards) or very conspicuous (which is bad for drawing attention from the Law)
Compare a set of Brass Knuckles, you can keep them in your pocket - no one knows you have them, until it's game time, put your hands in your pocket and half a second later, you're armed.

Now, compare with attaching anything to your foot - at minimum, it's 10 seconds, whilst you are bent over, vulnerable and it's pretty obvious what you are doing.

This is the biggest limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Brass knuckles guy if he has any awareness.  Your kicker has the problem that by kicking, he is seriously unstable, and putting his support where his opponent can easily knock him to the ground, by grabbing his leg.  Going to the ground is a *bad* thing.